# What are the two additional lines of output when I call ifelse

Tags: r

my R function is
`f2 <- function(x) { ifelse ( x > 50, print ("greater") , print("less") ) };`

I test the function using below code :

```
x<- c( 52, 49, 93, 31, 14);
f2(x);
```

This is the output I see

```
[1] "greater"
[1] "less"
[1] "greater" "less"    "greater" "less"    "less"
```

Question: what are the first two lines of the output ? I only expected the last line.

Comment: remove `print`  to get only the last line `f2 <- function(x){ifelse(x>50, "greater", "less")}`

Comment: I realized this was a duplicate question.